# Notification-less Foreground service

Tags: android, foreground-service, foregroundnotification

I understand that Google require to show notifications when using `Foreground Services`.
How then can apps, like Samsung Health, can run indefinitely and continue to collect my data without showing any notifications? Is it because they come pre-installed as system apps so they are exempted from this Google  requirement?

Comment: They're probably whitelisted yeah - system apps get permissions that third-party apps don't, and when device manufacturers have their own version of the OS (which they all do) they have the ability to give their own adaptations or apps extra privileges at the system level. Third-party apps don't get that much power, and have to follow the restrictions put in place because they're not trusted

Comment: @cactustictacs Do you know if an app can be whitelisted even though I've downloaded from the play-store?
I mean, I can download Samsung apps and Google apps which are not pre installed from the store can they still be whitelisted and exempted from the restrictions?

Comment: I'd say generally no, but that depends on the OS you're running. The restrictions are meant to enforce good behaviour, and alert the user to potential issues - e.g. if a foreground service is running, maybe you don't want that? But the first-party software can be considered "safe" and not something the user needs to be alerted to, which is why they whitelist their apps in the operating system itself. But some versions of Android *may* allow you to do something similar on a per-app basis (the user explicitly making this choice), and some custom roms might enable all restrictions to be removed

Comment: There's also *dedicated devices* (https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements/dedicated-device) and *fully managed devices* which allow an organisation more control over how the devices actually function, so it might be possible to whitelist things there somehow too (e.g. for something running in kiosk mode) but I don't know much about that side of things